# send mail using if else

Tags: php, if-statement, email

I have a form that takes the US I state  from a drop down menu  and opens a pdf based on the state value. I want to send a different email based on that value using PHP. I want to give them the choice of all 50+ states but since I only have to be concerned with three out of the 50 states I can hard code the email ie. myAAemail@mydomain.com, myBBemail@mydomain.com, and myCC@mydomain.com. I then want to put the state name or value on email but that is not a priority. Here are my if else statements how do I add the email? I sure I don’t have to mention that I am new to PHP.

```
}
if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'AA') {
    header("Location: aa.pdf");
} else if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'BB') {
    header("Location: bb.pdf");          
}else if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'CC') {
    header("Location: cc.pdf");          
}else {
    echo "Error processing form"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define an associative array with e-mails:

```
$emails = array(
    'AA' => 'email1@mydomain.com',
    'BB' => 'email2@mydomain.com',
    'CC' => 'email3@mydomain.com',
    'DD' => 'email4@mydomain.com',
    'EE' => 'email5@mydomain.com',
    // . . .
);
```

And use it as: `$mail_address = $emails[$_POST['recipient']];`.

```
}
if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'AA') {
    header("Location: aa.pdf");
} else if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'BB') {
    header("Location: bb.pdf");          
}else if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'CC') {
    header("Location: cc.pdf");          
}else {
    //Mark1
    if ( isset($_POST['recipient']) ) {
        echo "Error processing form"; 
    }
}

if ( isset($emails[$_POST['recipient']]) ) {
    $address = $emails[$_POST['recipient']];
    $subject = 'The mail about ' . $_POST['recipient'];
    $message = "Hello, I'm writing the mail about " . $_POST['recipient'];

    mail($address, $subject, $message);
} 

?>
```

Comment: How do I tie that in with opening the pdfs? I tried using an array for the email but couldn't open the correct pdf at the same time.

Comment: Great, it all works except the error message shows up before the form is even submitted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is "Error processing form"

Comment: I've changed the code. Look at the code after `//Mark1` comment. If your form is not submitted yet, error will not be showed. If form is submitted but you have strange `$_POST['recipient']`, the error will be showed.